# Argument type void is incomplete?

Tags: c, function

My program is supposed to convert a string to lowercase but I keep gettingg this error "Argument type void is incomplete" when trying to convert a string to lowercase and I don't know why. Could anyone explain why this is happening, thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
char str[25] ="HELLOWORLD";


void upperToLower(char *str){
  for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) {
    printf("%c", tolower((unsigned char) str[i]));
  }
}

int main(void) {
  upperToLower(str);
  printf("%s\n", upperToLower(str));
  return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: How do you expect a `void` return value to be printed?

Comment: `upperToLower` is supposed to return something, not print the result by itself. Well, at least it looks like it was intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `upperToLower` is supposed to modify the string in place. Try the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
char str[25] ="HELLOWORLD";


void upperToLower(char *str){
  for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) {
    str[i] = tolower((unsigned char) str[i]);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  upperToLower(str);
  printf("%s\n", str);
  return 0;
}
```

---

You could also make `upperToLower` return the pointer that was passed to it (like `strcpy` does with its first parameter). That allows the the `upperToLower` call to be done as part of the `printf` call like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
char str[25] ="HELLOWORLD";


char *upperToLower(char *str){
  for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) {
    str[i] = tolower((unsigned char) str[i]);
  }
  return str;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%s\n", upperToLower(str));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The return type of the function `upperToLower()` is `void`, so it cannot be used as a value in expressions.

The function `upperToLower()` prints things inside that, so you won't need to externally print something about that except for the newline character.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
char str[25] ="HELLOWORLD";


void upperToLower(char *str){
  for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) {
    printf("%c", tolower((unsigned char) str[i]));
  }
}

int main(void) {
  upperToLower(str);
  upperToLower(str); /* put this out of printf() */
  printf("\n"); /* and print just newline character here */
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As specified in [C specification](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p19) the type `void` is an incomplete type.

> The void type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete
> object type that
> cannot be completed.

As result it is not possible to form any value of type void. Pointers of type `void*` can be used, but they cannot be dereferenced.

Answer (score -1):

Your function returns void, you're literally passing nothing as a parameter.